# cmake not linking my class I think, mistakes in cmakelists.text likely culprit

Tags: cmake

I think, I may have improperly set up cmake wrong,(or improperly set up cmake for that matter) or I'm bad and rusty at C++ or both and possibly more. I just want to add a header and separate code into a class that loads images for opengl. I also put them in another directory parallel to other libraries in my linux file tree.

The main project folder has the main cmakelists.text file in it it's called "maficengine".  Inside it are also a "build" file a "common" file and "external" file and a file called "Mafic", "maficGuiSourceFiles" file and one called "distrib."  I think we can just focus on 2.  "mafic" and "external".  Inside mafic I have one called mafic.cpp  which has my main function and is the entry point.  Inside external, there is another folder called "myCustomHeaders".. therein lies a file called "loadTexture.cpp"  It contains the loadTexture class declaration and definition.  Also inside "myCustomHeaders" there is an "include" file which contains "loadTexture.h"... I cannot seem to instanciate an instance of LoadTexture lt; and call the function of loadtexture();  I expect it to at line 187 in mafic.cpp

```
#cmakelists.text file from main project folder

# CMake entry point
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)


project (maficengine )

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)



add_library(loaders
 external/myCustomHeaders/loadTexture.cpp
 external/myCustomHeaders/include/loadTexture.h
 )

  set(SOURCES  external/myCustomHeaders/loadTexture.cpp )



# Compile external dependencies 
add_subdirectory (external)


# On Visual 2005 and above, this module can set the debug working directory
cmake_policy(SET CMP0026 OLD)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0079  NEW)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/external/rpavlik-cmake-modules-fe2273")
include(CreateLaunchers)
include(MSVCMultipleProcessCompile) # /MP

if(INCLUDE_DISTRIB)
    add_subdirectory(distrib)
endif(INCLUDE_DISTRIB)



include_directories(
    external/AntTweakBar-1.16/include/
    external/glfw-3.1.2/include/
    external/glm-0.9.7.1/
    external/glew-1.13.0/include/
    external/assimp-3.0.1270/include/
    external/bullet-2.81-rev2613/src/
    external/myCustomHeaders/include
    common/
)

set(ALL_LIBS
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARY}
    glfw
    GLEW_1130
    loaders
)

add_definitions(
    -DTW_STATIC
    -DTW_NO_LIB_PRAGMA
    -DTW_NO_DIRECT3D
    -DGLEW_STATIC
    -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
)

# Tutorial 17
add_executable(mageengine
    Mafic/mafic.cpp
    common/shader.cpp
    common/shader.hpp
    common/controls.cpp
    common/controls.hpp
    common/texture.cpp
    common/texture.hpp
    common/objloader.cpp
    common/objloader.hpp
    common/vboindexer.cpp
    common/vboindexer.hpp
    common/quaternion_utils.cpp
    common/quaternion_utils.hpp
    #Mafic/loadTexture.h
    #Mafic/loadTexture.cpp
    Mafic/StandardShading.vertexshader
    Mafic/StandardShading.fragmentshader
)


target_link_libraries(mageengine
    ${ALL_LIBS}
    ANTTWEAKBAR_116_OGLCORE_GLFW
   loaders
)
```

here's mafic.cpp

```
#include <loadTexture.h>


int main( void )
{

loadTexture lt;

 lt.loadtexture();
 }
```

here's my loadTexture.cpp

```
class loadTexture
{

public:

loadTexture();

~loadTexture();

void loadtexture(){



fprintf(stdout, "loadtexture does something, that's a positive result for this test");



}




};
```

and finally my loadTexture.h

```
[code] 
#pragma once

#include <GL/glew.h>

//GLuint image;
void loadtexture();
[/code]
```

Hoping it would build with no errors but I get ...

```
aaron@Zog:~/Desktop/maficengine/build$ make 
[  2%] Built target ANTTWEAKBAR_116_OGLCORE_GLFW
[  2%] Built target GLEW_1130
[  2%] Built target loaders
[  6%] Built target glfw
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mageengine.dir/Mafic/mafic.cpp.o
/home/aaron/Desktop/maficengine/Mafic/mafic.cpp:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file
#pragma once
        ^~~~
/home/aaron/Desktop/maficengine/Mafic/mafic.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/aaron/Desktop/maficengine/Mafic/mafic.cpp:187:1: error: ‘loadTexture’ was not declared in this scope
loadTexture lt;
^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/aaron/Desktop/maficengine/Mafic/mafic.cpp:187:1: note: suggested alternative: ‘loadtexture’
loadTexture lt;
^~~~~~~~~~~
loadtexture
/home/aaron/Desktop/maficengine/Mafic/mafic.cpp:189:2: error: ‘lt’ was not declared in this scope
 lt.loadtexture();
 ^~
CMakeFiles/mageengine.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mageengine.dir/Mafic/mafic.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/mageengine.dir/Mafic/mafic.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:75: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mageengine.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mageengine.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
aaron@Zog:~/Desktop/maficengine/build$
```

Comment: `void loadtexture();` is not `void loadTexture::loadtexture()`. The `class loadTexture` is declared in cpp file, it's not visible outside.

Comment: You say "void loadtexture(); is not void loadTexture::loadtexture()."   Do you mean it should be? In which file if so?  I know the class was declared in loadTexture.cpp  and isn't visible outside,  so in mafic.cpp  I tried to make an object called "lt"  so I didn't try to access it directly.  Can I get some clarification, I've tried changing some of these things still getting undefined reference errors. Thanks for trying to help btw.

Comment: ok, I figured it out I think.. It is because i have never been a professional c++ user.  I confused the function of the header and the ,cpp..  I thought I wrote a class in the .cpp and just declared functions in the header.  But apparently I declare the class and functions in the header and just define the functions in the .cpp